# Non-Unique Index on sqllite database table in phonegap

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am using phonegap with the default database.
Reading this documentation, it does not mention anything about indexes on the database tables (aka PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE INDEX, or INDEX).
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

But when I look at example code:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/20/Example-of-PhoneGaps-Database-Support

I can see that Ray uses "PRIMARY KEY".

My three questions are:

1. Is there a definitive guide for all sql syntax supported in
   phonegap?
2. Are non-primary key indexes supported in phonegap?
3. Assuming #2, do the appropriately placed indexes speed up code (or
   are the keywords read and ignored)?

Answer (score 0):

For practical purposes, all PhoneGap implementations use SQLite, so you can use [everything supported by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).